Need to forward DNS requests for missed lookups with PowerDNS
I have a DNS server on prem that handles internal DNS resolution. We also have some records for the same domain hosted in Route53. I need to configure the pdns-recursor to forward the requests that aren't hosted on the internal DNS to a public server for resolution. I've tried a few options such as a specific subdomain in the recursor config as a forward-zone, and the server does forward that request, but I always get a SERVFAIL for it.
What can I do to forward all or at least a specific subdomain correctly?
